# calling Ropsten test network using Java

Tags: java, ethereum

I have been given a contract id and a abi Json file to make use of a test network. I want to be able to make calls to this contract using Java. but i have not been able to find any resources to do this.

Anyone have any resources?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://ropsten.infura.io/"));

    }
```

I have no API key as its someone else set it up, but i have the contract id and the ABI file.